# Angular material button change on hover

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can anyone provide an stackblitz example of an angular material button that changes color on hover?

The answers I found use ng::deep that looks like it will be removed?

```
    .link-btn /deep/ .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events with `[color]` property binding. Something like this:

```
<button 
  mat-raised-button 
  [color]="color" 
  (mouseover)="color = 'warn'"
  (mouseout)="color = 'accent'">
  Click me!
</button>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-button-change-color-on-hover?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: what about if multiple button in same page like menu

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

here is Stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xf75rm-twuv1h?file=src/app/button-types-example.css

add a class like `hover-class` :

```
<div class="example-button-row">
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="hover-class">Primary</button>
</div>
```

and in css:

```
.hover-class:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the Stackblitz link. :)

Comment: Sorry, Add it for you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simpler approach:

Idea is to change color if its not hovered.

**HTML**

```
<button mat-button color="primary"> Click me! </button>
```

**CSS:**

```
[mat-button]:not(:hover) {
  color: inherit;
}
```

you may alter selector as per your need and add `:focus` or any other pseudo selector you wish

Answer (score 0):

[I have created an example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hover-example)

You do not need to use ng::deep or /deep/ for this.